# Vulkan not working

Tags: nvidia, graphics, opengl, vulkan

( Also on [Nvidia forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/vulkan-not-working/220255) )

Fedora 36 with Gnome 42.2, everything up to date
Nvidia's latest proprietary drivers (515.57)
Nvidia Geforce GTX 745 and Intel Core i5-6400 (no integrated graphics)

Problem first occurred when launching Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire through Lutris (flatpak). I get a terrible framerate and upon launching Lutris (flatpak) through a terminal, I receive these errors:

```
libEGL warning: DRI3: Screen seems not DRI3 capable
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
libEGL warning: DRI3: Screen seems not DRI3 capable
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
2022-07-09 12:29:21,250: Invalid glxinfo received
```

And after `2022-07-09 12:29:21,644: Startup complete`:

```
2022-07-09 12:31:05,686: Unable to load libGLX_nvidia.so.0
2022-07-09 12:31:05,686: Unable to locate libGLX_nvidia
```

As soon as I run the game, I get this error while the game continues to run at a terrible framerate: `WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.`

This seems like my Vulkan drivers are messed up, so I tried to run OMORI through Lutris (RPM) and instantly receive these errors and the game refuses to start:

[image]
[image]

Trying to launch anyway gives me the normal Gnome application crash message ("Oops! We're sorry, it looks like OMORI crashed...")

Here's the output of glxinfo -B

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
    Dedicated video memory: 4096 MB
    Total available memory: 4096 MB
    Currently available dedicated video memory: 3883 MB
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 745/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 515.57
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 515.57
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 515.57
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

Here's the output of vulkaninfo

```
Cannot create Vulkan instance.
This problem is often caused by a faulty installation of the Vulkan driver or attempting to use a GPU that does not support Vulkan.
ERROR at /builddir/build/BUILD/Vulkan-Tools-sdk-1.3.204.0/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.h:649:vkCreateInstance failed with ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER
```

`lspci -k` shows that my GPU is using the "nvidia" driver like it's supposed to.

I checked through `/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/` and `/etc/vulkan/icd.d/` and both of them were empty. Could this be the problem? How could I get my graphics thingies working?

Comment: Please ask here https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to a new file in `/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json` fixed the issue:

```
{
    "file_format_version" : "1.0.0",
    "ICD": {
        "library_path": "libGLX_nvidia.so.0",
        "api_version" : "1.3.204"
    }
}
```

That API version I just randomly pulled from the vulkaninfo error text and it worked.